# c++ creating universal point template

Tags: c++, templates

to start I am very new to c++, so there might be just a stupid syntax error. I am trying to create a header file, where I want to create template for point, so that the point can have any amount of coordinates. Like Point <2> would have x and y coordinates. Point <3> would have x,y,z and so on. When I am using this header with test program it does not compile. Can anyone help me?

```
using std::ostream;

using std::list;

template <unsigned short n>

class Point {

public:



Point <n>() = default; 

Point <n>(list<float> coords){


    this-> coords=coords;
    }


    float distanceFrom (Point <n> p){
        float s=0;
        auto it1= coords.begin();
        auto it2= p.coords.begin();
        while ((it) != coords.end()){
            s+=(*it1 -*it2)*(*it1-*it2);
            it1++;
            it2++;
        }
    return sqrt(s);
    }

};
#endif
```

Comment: Please always give the compiler message instead of just saying that it does not compile.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's valid in C++ `Point <n>() = default; `

Comment: Oh, 12 different point classes! What's needed is a *universal* point class! -- and then there were 13.

Comment: after defining coords, now there is error:   include/point.h:38:16: error: there are no arguments to ’sqrtä that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ’sqrt’ muste be available [-fpermissive] return sqrt(s);

Comment: @cheersandhth.-alf The problem with standards is that there just are not enough.

Comment: @TheMask It is valid C++11 code, it explicitly defines the default constructor to be the default implementation (of the default constructor ^^)

Comment: can anybody help me with my last error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to a class member `coords`, which is not declared.

Simply add the declaration `list<float> coords;` to your class.

To fix your second problem, you need to make a `sqrt` declaration available. To do so, you need to `#include <cmath>`, which will provide [`::std::sqrt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt). Remember to add a `using ::std::sqrt` or similar statement to ensure that it is known as `sqrt`.

Comment: `list<float> coords;` wouldn't limit the number of point coordinates to `n`.

Comment: It is also my first time to use stackoverflow. I will post the exact message in the future. :) Yes, you are right the problem was that coords was undefined. But adding list<float coords>; still says that coords not defined.